# What is the best practice for running a background process as www-data while running apache2 under debian?

Tags: background, apache2.4, debian-buster

What is the best practice for running  a background process as www-data while running apache2 under debian?

I have cgi processes building mail lists and was running a background process as user fred to process the lists.  The cgi processes put the lists in a bespoke folder, and the process running as user fred would process and then archive the lists.

Now I want to stop (kill) the process that is running as user fred from a web page, but apache2 does not have the correct permissions to do this.

So I am thinking that I should move the process from fred to www-data.

I have never had a long running process (other than apache2 itself) running as www-data.

What are the best practices?

Thanks,

Jim